# How to remove text added in wordpress admin bar?

Tags: wordpress

[image: Admin bar]

I'm new to wordpress . By mistake I added a "//" character in Admin bar, now I'm not being able to remove it. To remove this character which file need to be modified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The file where you added it might be a good start.

Comment: I was trying out smthing, So I'm sure where I had added it.

Comment: Well, if you edited core wordpress files you can just download it again and replace all files with the original versions. They would be overwritten on the next update anyway. Same goes for plugins or themes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , it was inside JS files of wordpress